# Java ThreadPoolExecutor [Submit More Than MaxPoolSize]

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, threadpool

I have an app that allows users to batch add watermarks to images. The app would only use one thread and can only add one watermark at a time.

I want the user to be able to change the **number** of **watermark** **tasks[threads]** running at a time: maybe **[1-5]** in settings, and I can't use a fixedThreadPool, as it has a fixed pool size.

I looked into using a **ThreadPoolExecutor** `private static ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newCachedThreadPool();` and each time the user changes the number of threads I invoke the *ThreadPoolExecutor*.*setMaxPoolSize*(**newMaxThreadCount**).

Now when I try to submit say **15 image watermark tasks** to the executor with a maximum pool size of **3**,
I get the following exception:

> ***java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task com.darkmental.zeondownloader.app.main.phototools.watermark.BulkWatermarkTask$$Lambda$710/1861585081@1e2d8ad4 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@24d02747[Running, pool size = 3, active threads = 3, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]***

I expected the **ThreadPoolExecutor** to have the same behavior as a **fixedThreadPool** where I can have a pool size of **10** and still submit **as many** tasks as I want, but I didn't. How can I do that?

Comment: When you want a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, you should use `new ThreadPoolExecutor(…)` and not abuse a factory method that intentionally specifies a more abstract return type.

Answer (score 3):

A look at the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) shows, that this behaviour is intended.

> New tasks submitted in method execute(java.lang.Runnable) will be rejected when the Executor has been shut down, and also when the Executor **uses finite bounds for both maximum threads and work queue capacity**, and is saturated.

So in your case, your queue seems to be full or doesn't accept any new items.
I haven't seen how you actually created your `ThreadPoolExecutor`, but I would guess, that you need to specify a sufficent `BlockingQueue` in the constructor.

**EDIT:** This probably happens, because `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` is unbounded and creates a new Thread every time, if there is no cached Thread available. However setting the maximum pool size interferes with this and the task is rejected via the `RejectedExecutionHandler`.

I currently can't reproduce the scenario, but you probably can change the active `AbortPolicy` to `ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy` via `setRejectedExecutionHandler(ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy)`. This result in the calling Thread to execute the new tasks instead of throwing an Exception.

Comment: Thank you, i edited my question. I created it using Executors.newCachedThreadPool()

Comment: @RafatRifaie I have edited my answer to reflect that. You should probably consider using a simple `Executors.newFixedThreadPool`. I don't think the Thread creation is such a big overhead, that you would gain from using a cached pool, which has this drawback.